# TRMM 3B42RT product has no Coordinate Reference System?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, resolution, precipitation, trmm

When I download TRMM precipitation product 3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day and when opening it in QGIS the raster has no CRS and is seen in another place with a smaller resolution, I already tried reprojecting and assigning it an CRS and it continues the same.

Comment: Do you have _.tif_ and _.tfw_ both files?

Comment: I am downloading from this link
ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/gis/
... I am also executing this code in R, to trim with a polygon and evaluate its spatial resolution, but I get an error because it does not find the raster's SRC.

Comment: Please, edit the question to provide additional information.

Comment: The Georeference is in the _.tfw_ file, you need to download it, and both _.tif_ and _.tfw_ must have the same name. Gdal will recognize it and you can wrap it to the CRS that you want. https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#georeferencing

Comment: thank you very much sensei

Comment: You're welcome! Sensei really are some in this community. In most of the topics that concern us, including in the manipulation of raster files and mainly in the domain of GDAL libraries. But I'm definitely not one of them! Thanks also.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look first at the information provided by `gadlinfo` for the *3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tif* file:

```
C:\>gdalinfo 3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tif
Size is 1440, 480
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2016:01:05 19:28:31
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=./image/3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tif
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=IDL TIFF file
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IDL 7.1.1, ITT Visual Information Solutions
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=100
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=100
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  480.0)
Upper Right ( 1440.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 1440.0,  480.0)
Center      (  720.0,  240.0)
Band 1 Block=1440x2 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Indeed, the file does not include its Coordinate Reference System. However, on the server there is also published the world file that brings georeferencing. Its name is *3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tfw* and its content is:

```
      0.2500000
      0.0000000
      0.0000000
     -0.2500000
   -179.8750000
     59.8750000
```

If we check again the information of the GeoTIFF file, having in the same folder both files with the same name as they are provided, we see that GDAL recognizes the georeferencing:

```
C:\>gdalinfo 3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tif
       3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tfw
Size is 1440, 480
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,60.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2016:01:05 19:28:31
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=./image/3B42RT.2016010100.7.7day.tif
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=IDL TIFF file
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IDL 7.1.1, ITT Visual Information Solutions
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=100
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=100
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  60.0000000)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -60.0000000)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  60.0000000)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -60.0000000)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000)
Band 1 Block=1440x2 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Everything seems to indicate that it is an [Equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection). Even so, the information can be ambiguous. We do not know the datum on which the coordinates are referred. For that we must refer to the [Documentation](https://pmm.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/document_files/3B4XRT_doc_V7_180426.pdf):

[image: 1]

Knowing that the datum is WGS84, we already have all the necessary information about the CRS of the dataset.

---

Link within the documentation of the GDAL library on georeferencing for the GeoTIFF file format driver:
https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#georeferencing

Article about world files on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file